# Unit testing SSL pinning with URLProtocol

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, nsurlprotocol, public-key-pinning, custom-url-protocol

**Aim:** Unit test app's ssl pinning

**Approximate implementation aimed for:**

1. subclass URLProtocol
2. Insert custom URLProtocol into Session's configuration
3. Use session with custom config when generating requests
4. catch the request and generate response with local certificate
5. expect that when the app receives the response it will detect the same certificate

**Problem encountered:**

There seems to be no authentication challenge method to subclass in the URLProtocol.

**Question:**

How to intercept auth challenge with URLProtocol?

Comment: Have you looked at creating an auth challenge and calling `urlProtocol(_, didReceive:)` on the protocol client?

Comment: @Mats not yet.. how would you envision using this?

Comment: The challenge with that approach seems to be the fact that I cannot provide the server trust ivar of the URLProtectionSpace which is basically needed to extract server certificate [to compare it with local one after].

Comment: I haven’t tried it, but would subclassing URLProtectionSpace solve this?

Comment: @Mats can be something... will try today

Comment: Did try overriding URLProtectionSpace, but it seems like even though it's definitely my protection space data [like host and port being sent back with the auth challenge triggered by calling client.didreceive] the server trust is actually not passed and in the session delegate I get a nil server trust...

Comment: @Mats I have posted a question specifically about subclassing URLProtectionSpace. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517742/subclassing-urlprotectionspace

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. @Fawkes did you solve this in the end?

Comment: @MichaelVoong unfortunately did not find a way so I've ended up putting that logic into a small utility class and mocking that one to see if it's called.